# One of my C++ program failed in the grader of USACO Online Judge

Tags: c++, c++14

I am solving a problem (Mixing Milk, milk) on USACO Online Judge. On my computer (Windows 10 20H2) it worked perfectly, but on the OJ it failed while running. It shows this:

> Execution error: Your program exited with exit status
> `127'.
> Your program printed data to stderr.  Here is the data:
> -------------------
> program:_error_while_loading_shared_libraries:_libstdc++.so.6:_failed_to_map_segment_from_shared_object
> -------------------

I have serched on Google for two days, but no help. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

My code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

int n, m;
struct node {
    int p, a;
    friend bool operator < (const node &x, const node &y) {
        return x.p < y.p;
    }
} f[2000000];

void input() {
    freopen("milk.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("milk.out", "w", stdout);
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        scanf("%d%d", &f[i].p, &f[i].a);
}

void work() {
    std::sort(f, f+m);
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; n; i++) {
        int val = std::min(f[i].a, n);
        n -= val;
        ans += val * f[i].p;
    }
    printf("%d\n", ans);
}

int main() {
    input();
    work();
    return 0;
}
```

The input file:

```
100 5
5 20
9 40
3 10
8 80
6 30
```

The gcc version: 9.3.0

The C++ version: C++14

Comment: The site may be limiting the size of global data that you are allowed to use. Use a `std::vector` instead of the array and see whether it will work better.

Comment: I know the reason: the problem is asking me to use a array with a size `5 000` but I make a `2 000 000` one.